# Samsung Galaxy Player 5.0 can't connect to any of Google services

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, gmail, samsung-galaxy-player

I'm not really sure if this question is fit for this site, but a few days ago my Samsung Galaxy Player 5.0 stopped being able to connect to Gmail, Google Talk and Play Store using their respective apps on the device, also the device isn't able to connect to the GCM service.

The device is running Gingerbread 2.3.5 and isn't rooted.

Can someone explain to me what is going on with my device? In case this question isn't fit for this forum I'll ask for moving it to a different forum. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**
More information:

- Device is connected to internet.
- I am logged with a Google Account.
- Router isn't the problem, other devices are able to connect to the
  services I described previously.
- The device doesn't lose access to
  the internet.

Comment: Is internet still accessible? Did you try to switch off/on your player and wifi router?

Comment: yes, there's no problem with the internet connection at all since I can open web pages but the Google services apps (Hangouts, Gmail, Maps, etc) can't get access

Comment: Are you logged in in your Google account?

Comment: yes, I am logged with a Google account